# Segmenting sentence into subsentences with CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing, nlp, pycorenlp

I am working on the following problem: I would like to split sentences into subsentences using Stanford CoreNLP. The example sentence could be:

```
"Richard is working with CoreNLP, but does not really understand what he is doing"
```

I would now like my sentence to be split into single "S" as shown in the tree diagram below:

[image]

I would like the output to be a list with the single "S" as follows:

```
['Richard is working with CoreNLP', ', but', 'does not really understand what', 'he is doing']
```

I would be really thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the tool you're looking for is [Tregex](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.html), described in more detail in the power point [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex/The_Wonderful_World_of_Tregex.ppt/) or the [Javadoc](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html) of the class itself.

In your case, I believe the pattern you're looking for is simply `S`. So, something like:

```
tregex.sh “S” <path_to_file>
```

where the file is a Penn Treebank formatted tree -- that is, something like `(ROOT (S (NP (NNS dogs)) (VP (VB chase) (NP (NNS cats)))))`.

As an aside: I believe the fragment "*, but*" is not actually a sentence, as you've hightlighted in the figure. Rather, the node you've highlighted subsumes the whole sentence "*Richard is working with CoreNLP, but does not really understand what he is doing*". Tregex would then print out this whole sentence as one of the matches. Similarly, "*does not really understand what*" is not a sentence unless it subsumes the entire SBAR: "*does not understand what he is doing*".

If you want just the "leaf" sentences (i.e., a sentence that's not subsumed by another sentence), you can try a pattern more like:

```
S !>> S
```

---

Note: I haven't tested the patterns -- use at your own risk!

Comment: Thank you for your response. We are working in Python. Do you know how we could integrate your solution here? That would be really great!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that one do this as follows:

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:9000/tregex"
request_params = {"pattern": "S"}
text = "Pusheen and Smitha walked along the beach."
r = requests.post(url, data=text, params=request_params)
print r.json()
```

Does anybody know how to use other languages (I need German)?